# Create directories and populate with phython files

Tags: python, file, directory

I have a txt file with the following configuration:

```
---01---2125---1648---
random words
random words
---01---3068---1648---
random words
random words
---02---3068---1648---
random words
random words
```

The goal is to create a directory and in that directory insert files according to the directory it belongs to. All of this with the names given there in the file data_base.txt. Example:

```
data_base
|_01/
|  |_2125.txt
|  |_3068.txt
|
|_02/
|  |_3068.txt
|
```

and so on...The txt files will be filled with their respective random words. The code is getting as below:

```
import glob, os
from os.path import isfile

path = "/Users/text"
os.mkdir(path)
fp = open("data_base.txt", 'r', -1)
codes = fp.readlines()
for i in codes:
    print(i.replace("---"," ").strip())
```

I was able to remove the strings "---" between the numbers, using the replace function. The problem is that I'm not getting it right by searching for the string that would be the name of the directories (01, 02, etc.).

Does anyone have any idea how to insert the respective strings as directory names?

Comment: [Can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) -- your final sentence is *not* the proper focus for a Stack Overflow question.  Can you re-word this to your *specific* need, please?

Comment: @Prune Okay, the question was adequate. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file, line by line.  When you encounter a line beginning with `---`, dont replace those; rather ...

```
path = line.split("---")
```

This will return your desired fields: path[0] is empty; path[01] is the direcotry; path[2] is the file; the rest (apparently) is garbage for you.

Keep track of your directory name.  When you get a new directory name, you have to create it; otherwise, you just add a new file.

This much should get you moving; each of these steps is well-documented elsewhere on line.